# How to integrate third party billing engine in WSO2 API Manager 1.10?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have installed API Manager & DAS server. I want to install billing system. Is there any link which will help me to integrate or install billing system with wso2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use third party billing systems like zuora or coral and plug it to API Manager to do your billing. You can simply do this by using API_REQUEST_SUMMARY table generated in DAS, and send that API level data to your billing engine to bill per API.

If you want to configure  API Monetization please refer [1]

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Configuring+API+Monetization+Category+Labels